# What does this command with a backslash at the end do?

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

```
curl -L https://github.com/dhiltgen/docker-machine-kvm/releases/download/v0.10.0/docker-machine-driver-kvm-ubuntu14.04 > /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-kvm \
```

It downloads a file called `docker-machine-driver-kvm-ubuntu14.04`, and then? sends it to the directory `/usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-kvm`?

Also, what about the `\` at the end?

Comment: Looks like an error. Does it even work? Actually it extends the line, allowing you to continue the command on the next line, if needed.

Answer (score 32):

That looks like an error if the line is to be interpreted by itself.

A backslash escapes the next character from being interpreted by the shell.  If the next character after the backslash is a newline character, then that newline will not be interpreted as the end of the command by the shell. Instead, it effectively allows a command to span multiple lines.

It is common to break long lines in this manner when you want to make it easier to read a long command:

```
rsync --archive \
      --verbose \
      user@source:/dir/ \
      user@target:/dir/
```

Notice that the last line should not have an `\` at the end since it is the last line. Note that *nothing* (not even a comment or a single space) may follow the `\` on the lines broken up in this way.

In conclusion, yes, the command downloads a file and saves it to a file on disk.  Another way of doing the same thing, without a redirection, would be to use the `-o` option with `curl`:

```
curl -L \
    -o /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-kvm \
    https://github.com/dhiltgen/docker-machine-kvm/releases/download/v0.10.0/docker-machine-driver-kvm-ubuntu14.04 \
```

(followed by whatever is on the following line in your script)

Comment: Ah, ok. So I think the next character was newline.
so there is a command after that. Thanks

Comment: @StaticBug Strictly speaking probably not a command, but the continuation of the `curl` command.